# Separating a string according to fixed lengths in R, to create columns

Tags: r, string, dataframe

I have a list of strings that I would like to turn into a dataframe.  I would like to delimit each string according to some fixed length, for example, let's say my list looks like:

```
text = c("ABC      ABC BROWNIES COMPANY            1/31/2009",
         "BCD      BCD BROWNIES COMPANY            1/31/2009")
```

and I want to turn it into the dataframe that would result if I used:

```
FINAL <- data.frame(rbind(c("ABC", "ABC BROWNIES COMPANY","1/31/2009"),c("BCD", "BCD BROWNIES COMPANY","1/31/2009")),stringsAsFactors = F)

colnames(FINAL) = c("Ticker","Company","Date")
```

FINAL

Basically I want to introduce some sort of fixed-length delimiting to separate the items in each element of "text."
I don't think I can use strsplit because I don't really have one character on which to split (spaces won't work because some of my entries contain spaces, and there are uneven spaces from "Ticker" to "Company" and "Company" to "Date").

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you mention fixed length delimiting, maybe give `read.fwf` a try.

```
read.fwf(textConnection(text), widths = c(3, 21, 13), 
         col.names = c("Ticker", "Company", "Date"))
#   Ticker               Company       Date
# 1    ABC  ABC BROWNIES COMPANY  1/31/2009
# 2    BCD  BCD BROWNIES COMPANY  1/31/2009
```

You can mess around with the middle `21` value to get it to work on all the data.

Another possibility is to split on three or more spaces.

```
data.frame(do.call(rbind, strsplit(text, " {3,}")))
#    X1                   X2        X3
# 1 ABC ABC BROWNIES COMPANY 1/31/2009
# 2 BCD BCD BROWNIES COMPANY 1/31/2009
```

Comment: Thank you so much everyone for your input!  I'm going to go with read.fwf, since sometimes in my data the columns will only be separated by one space -- but this is great, so many new things I've learned =)

Answer (score 1):

Either use read.fwf or substitute long spans of spaces with a delimiter.

```
> read.table( text=gsub(" {3,10}", ",", text), sep="," )
   V1                   V2          V3
1 ABC ABC BROWNIES COMPANY   1/31/2009
2 BCD BCD BROWNIES COMPANY   1/31/2009
```

Comment: To play the SO game correctly, you now need to give Richard the checkmark

Answer (score 0):

Possibly `str_split_fixed` from `stringr`:

```
library(stringr)
##
Df <- data.frame(
  str_split_fixed(text,pattern="\\s{2,}",3),
  stringsAsFactors=F)
##
names(Df) <- c("Ticker","Company","Date")
##
> Df
  Ticker              Company      Date
1    ABC ABC BROWNIES COMPANY 1/31/2009
2    BCD BCD BROWNIES COMPANY 1/31/2009
> str(Df)
'data.frame':   2 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ Ticker : chr  "ABC" "BCD"
 $ Company: chr  "ABC BROWNIES COMPANY" "BCD BROWNIES COMPANY"
 $ Date   : chr  "1/31/2009" "1/31/2009"
```

which assumes that 2 or more consecutive spaces indicates a new column; although this could be adjusted if necessary.

Comment: The newer version of ["string**i**"](https://github.com/Rexamine/stringi) have a `simplify` argument, that would let you do the following: `stri_split_regex(text, "\\s{3,}", simplify = TRUE)`.

Comment: Thanks so much!  I just downloaded stringr, and I didn't realize it could do so many things!